# Interactive Firewall

Tags: 10.04, server, firewall

I have Ubuntu Server 10.04 serving as router/firewall with iptables. Also have number of client computers in LAN. So far so good.

Now what I need is some sort of interactive firewall software on server, which I can turn on and it will ask me to allow/disallow outgoing connection (from console) from my particular LAN PCs through firewall to internet. Ultimate goal is to suspend all kind of suspicious connections/calls to home. Currently this job is done using Little Snitch on each MacOS computer, causing additional load on each client to monitor for outgoing traffic (not to mention that it's paid app). So I thought maybe it's possible to centralize it on my Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a firewall does not exist on Linux. The netfilter/IPtables firewall system cannot filter applications.

Ubuntu users have been asking for the creation of a program that can filter applications and log internet connections. Currently, there is suggestions and discussion about possibly using AppArmor coupled with IPtables to fulfill this need. You are welcome to participate in the discussion and advocate for the creation of this kind of software. You can sign up and learn more about the discussion list here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-devel-discuss